# VS Code on linux, various permissions errors

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to get vs code to work properly in linux? I can't run `sudo code .` because that gives me an error saying it's not secure to do so, I can't do anything within the editor to force doing things, like staging a file in git, or reloading a newly installed extension. I've googled around, and it seems nobody else has posted about this, and it seems highly unlikely that I'm the first to raise issue about this. (Take it easy on me, I'm a relatively new linux user). I'm trying to figure this out on Ubuntu 18.04 if that's relevant at all. My version of vs code is 1.30.2

I guess my main question is what's the right way to get applications like vs code to be able to perform tasks that required doing things without fighting the OS about sudo and privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Launch via `sudo` from terminal

To launch VSCode as root --*which is highly discouraged*-- you must specify an alternate user data directory as follows:

```
$ sudo code --user-data-dir /path/to/alternate/folder
```

VSCode will automatically generate the required folders in the selected directory and launch with root privileges.

---

#### Change permissions to fix "permission denied" error

The solution in this case is to manually change the permissions of the two directories `/home/$USER/.config/Code/` and `/home/$USER/.vscode/`. Perform these steps:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /home/$USER/.config/Code
```

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /home/$USER/.vscode
```

---

#### To answer your other question:

If you really need to run several commands as root and you are annoyed by having to enter your password several times (when sudo has expired), just do `sudo -i` and you'll become root.

If you want to run commands using pipes, use `sudo sh -c "comand1 | command2"`.

> You may also want to take a look at [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617767/833898) about running applications as root.

Comment: so the problem for me is that I can't do something like update an extension without launching vs code as root, or even do a git pull through the git interface within vs code itself. The sudo blocking me is rendering all the nice features of vs code pointless. I'm not prompted to enter my password, I just get permission denied if I try to use any of the GUI elements of vs code within ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, understood. I've updated my answer. I'll continue investigating in this.

Comment: "The solution in this case is to manually change the permissions of the two directories" -- Okay, but what is this actually doing? I mean, I understand what chmodding to 755 does in terms of setting permissions on those *directories*, but what does this mean in terms of the permissions the app inherits when it opens/runs? I'm a developer new to Linux too and facing similar issues with PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem using:

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USER YOUR_PROJECT/
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to tell the OS that you are the owner of the files you create. Use `sudo chown <user name> <projects directory>`
However, if you already created some files before applying chown, don't forget to change their permission also `sudo chown <user name> <projects directory>/<file name>`.