# Cant write files to /var/www/html using the VS Code editor

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, fedora, fedora-27

I am trying to save a .php file to /var/www/html/mysql using VS Code on Fedora 27 but I get an message saying

[image]

Also if I try to open VS Code as root I get the following message:

[image]

Comment: Basically this is a system administration thing, and I bet superuser.com is the best place to ask.

You'll need to learn to read the error messages - they already told you everything.

VS Code is correct. Learn some basics about permissions on UNIX-like systems (plus something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) can help you understand the problem.

Comment: The first error message says that I need to retry as Sudo. This is like entering root password every time I hit Command + S. Now if I open up VS Code as root I have to specify an alternate user data directory every time.

Comment: Well, the first error message says "**Select** 'Retry as Sudo'". It's a button in the dialog. Sudo is not a person nor a user. It's a command, allowing you to *su* and *do*.

Comment: @renyuneyun And this Retry as Sudo has to be done everytime I try to write the file ie press Command + S.

Comment: Running GUI applications as root is strongly discouraged AFAIK. I would say any sane people should not do so. That's why VS Code tries not to let you run it as root in the first place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If everything you want is 1. keep using VS Code to write your code/webpage 2. directly writing to `/var/www/html`, the most simple solution is to change the permission of that directory to allow your user to write. But, as mentioned above, this is a bad option AFAIK. I would suggest you write the file somewhere else, and copy them to `/var/www/html`.

Comment: @MohsinYaqoob Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745680/9110128) and simply run VSCode from terminal via `code --user-data-dir /path/to/alternate/folder` as normal user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change access rights to the folder. There are 2 options.

1. sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/mysql - Changes access rights to the mysql directory
2. sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/mysql - Changes access rights to both the mysql directory and all subdirectories inside.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the accepted answer actually works, I don't recommend to change access rights when using LINUX. Your "web" folder is usually owned by web server's user and group, therefore, it's a good practice to keep the same in your DEV (local) environment (i.e. your PC). It is OK to execute your IDE as sudo if you need to, as long as you handle it locally and keep the same access rights as in QA and PRODUCTION environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Visual Studio Code as root

`sudo code /directory-to-open --user-data-dir='/var/www/html/' --no-sandbox`

Or

`sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"`

Running Visual Studio Code as root is not recommended, as it can be dangerous and compromise your system’s security.

Another way

you can change the permissions of /var/www/html/ to allow your regular user to save files there. so you can run VSCode as a normal user and make changes to the file without any problem.

command change the owner of the folder to your user:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/`

Or

to change the permissions of the folder to allow read and write access for your user:

`sudo chmod -R u+rw /var/www/html/`